# Percentage of a text value from two columns

Tags: function, powerbi, dax, percentage, measure

I have two tables, 1 Main and large table with fields such as Industry, Area, Country etc:

[image]

the second table also contains same columns but it's a small table which shows performance of small team.

I want to calculate penetration percentage of Industry of this small team(abc) calculated from base value taken from large table.

So basically if let us say large table has total 700 rows out of which Manufacturing Industry rows are 300, and small table has manufacturing industry rows 30, so the penetration of small team Industry wise is 10% , so I want to calculate penetration % Industry wise, Area Wise, Country wise etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any slicers or anything, you could do this by creating a new table.
That table should have a DISTINCT of the Industry Column. And two columns, one would be a countrows of the large table filtered by the Industry. And the other one would be the same, but counting the rows of the small table.